# Language Pack for Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated)

Tags: visual-studio, localization

I'm trying to find the Language Pack for Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated). All I've been able to find was the one for Visual Studio 2015, but not the Shell version. The one for the main version does not install if you try to run it with the Shell installed. I also tried installing another language version of the Shell, but received an error when trying to launch the application built on the Shell.

Microsoft has been no help and either redirects me to another group who also doesn't help, or sends me information I've already tried. I tried posting on their Q&A area, and it gave me a 404 error when I hit post.

I tried installing this: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=VS%202015%20Language%20Pack
I tried installing this with a different language selected: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=VS%202015%20Language%20Pack

Neither got me what I needed.